# Computed column cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, computed-column

I know this is not the first time this type of question has been asked.

But why in the following scenario is the persisted computed column being created "non-deterministic". The answer should always be the same, right?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (Id INT, EventTime DATETIME NULL, PosixTime INT NOT NULL)
GO

DECLARE @EventTime DATETIME =  '20181001 12:00:00'
DECLARE @GPSTime INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', @EventTime)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Id, EventTime, PosixTime) 
VALUES (1, @EventTime, @GPSTime)
    , (2, NULL, @GPSTime)
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.test
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD UTCTime AS CONVERT(DATETIME2,ISNULL(EventTime, DATEADD(SECOND, PosixTime, CONVERT(DATE,'19700101'))),112) PERSISTED
GO
```

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 42 Computed column 'UTCTime' in
>   table 'test' cannot be persisted because the column is
>   non-deterministic.

I think I'm following the [deterministc rules here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017).

Is it possible to create a persisted computed column here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Converting a string to a date without a style number is not deterministic, also there is no reason to use a style number when converting a date or datetime to datetime2. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.test 
    ADD UTCTime AS CONVERT(datetime2,ISNULL(EventTime, 
    DATEADD(SECOND, PosixTime, CONVERT(datetime,'1970-01-01',120)))) 
    PERSISTED;
```

Though I'm curious why you need to persist this column. If it is so you can index it, you don't need to persist a column to index it...

Answer (score 11):

You need to use a deterministic style when converting from a *string* representation.

You were not using a deterministic style with the conversion from string to `date`.

You were unnecessarily specifying a style when converting from date to `datetime2`.

There is a confusing mixture of date/time data types in the question.

This works (producing a `datetime` column):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.test 
ADD UTCTime AS 
    ISNULL
    (
        EventTime,
        DATEADD
        (
            SECOND, 
            PosixTime, 
            CONVERT(datetime, '19700101', 112)
        )
    )
    PERSISTED;
```

As Aaron mentioned (we were answering concurrently), you do not need to persist a deterministic column to index it.